# How do I straighten a curved line in Illustrator and maintain its length?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, vector, line-art

How would I take this line and straighten it in illustrator without losing any of its length (Like if you held pulled a thread tight by both ends.) 
[image: curved line]

Comment: If I am understanding your question correctly: Why don’t you used measure its length (not sure whether Illustrator has this, but Inkscape does) and generate a new path with that length and the same style?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**You don't.** Pulling or dragging something to straighten out a multi-curved path is not possible as far as I'm aware. You could move *each and every* anchor point, but then you'd be hard pressed to not alter the length of the curves as you moved points.

You **can** get the length and draw a new path.

Choose `Window > Document Info`, then in the **Document Info Panel Menu** set it to `Objects` and select your path. It will tell you the length of the path.

Draw a new path that length.

[image]

Comment: That's perfect. I've used the 'info' window before, but wasn't aware of 'document info'. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

Have you tried resetting the Bezier curves using the pen tool? If you select and hold the pen tool from the sidebar 4 options should appear, select "anchor point tool" (shortcut for all of this is P > Shift + C) and simply click the anchor point. It'll remove the handles from that specific anchor point. When two points have no handles they become a straight line.